# Internet Explorer opens Word file corrupted

Tags: internet-explorer, download, ms-word, docx

I have a word file "confirm.docx" uploaded in my local storage. I simply download it by giving its path at `href`. It works perfect in Chrome and Firefox. The file is downloaded when I click the button. However in Explorer, it opens a new tab with corrupted characters like;

> PK!ð!ì}Ž[Content_Types].xml ¢(
>   ´”MOÂ@†ï&þ‡f¯¦]ð`Œ¡pP<*‰ÏËv »ÙY¾þ½Ó4@QðÒ¤Ý}        ß÷ÙÙÎô+]D
>   ð¨¬IY7é°Œ´™2Ó”½Ÿã{a&…5²5 ô¯¯zãµŒHm0e³Üç(g
>   &Ö¡•Üz-½ú)wB~Š)ðÛNçŽKk˜‡Òƒõ{O‹y¢áŠ>×$

The HTML code I use for downloading the file is:

```
<a href="/project/api/public/document/content/confirm.docx"
    target="_blank" class="">Download Agreement</a>
```

What could the problem be?

Comment: What do you mean by "local storage" exactly? The local storage of the browser only supports strings.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem and found an answer: 
I added this to the .htaccess

```
<FilesMatch "\.(?i:docx)$">
ForceType application/octet-stream
Header set Content-Disposition attachment
</FilesMatch>
```

I found it here: http://www.tipsandtricks-hq.com/forum/topic/force-a-file-to-download-instead-of-showing-up-in-the-browser